# ReferenceError with lottie-react on Next.js 13 - SSR Incompatibility?

Tags: next.js, server-side-rendering, lottie

I'm encountering a bug in my Next.js 13 application after installing lottie-react. When I compile my project, it completes successfully, but I get a ReferenceError stating that document is not defined. Here's the error log:

```
 ✓ Compiled in 104ms (1559 modules)
 ⨯ ReferenceError: document is not defined
    at createTag (/Users/thomas/starknetid/app.starknet.id/node_modules/lottie-web/build/player/lottie.js:30:5)
    at /Users/thomas/starknetid/app.starknet.id/node_modules/lottie-web/build/player/lottie.js:1316:20
    at /Users/thomas/starknetid/app.starknet.id/node_modules/lottie-web/build/player/lottie.js:1323:6
    at /Users/thomas/starknetid/app.starknet.id/node_modules/lottie-web/build/player/lottie.js:1540:4
    at /Users/thomas/starknetid/app.starknet.id/node_modules/lottie-web/build/player/lottie.js:2:83
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/thomas/starknetid/app.starknet.id/node_modules/lottie-web/build/player/lottie.js:5:3)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1376:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1435:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1207:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1023:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1235:19)
    at mod.require (/Users/thomas/starknetid/app.starknet.id/node_modules/next/dist/server/require-hook.js:64:28)
    at require (node:internal/modules/helpers:176:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/thomas/starknetid/app.starknet.id/node_modules/lottie-react/build/index.js:5:14)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1376:14) {
  page: '/register/testingdomain.stark'
}
```

I suspect this issue might be related to server-side rendering (SSR) incompatibility with lottie-react. In a typical client-side environment, document would be defined, but in SSR, document is not available.

Is there a workaround or a best practice for using lottie-react with Next.js in an SSR context? Do I need to check if SSR is enabled for every component that uses lottie?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is caused by the way one of the dependencies handles server and browser environments, it's a known bug but they didn't say when it's getting patched at least not in this answer which explains it much better than me:
https://github.com/Gamote/lottie-react/issues/101

Using node version 18 should fix it because it allows for the existing browser/server. Check the GitHub issue for more details.

Answer (score 3):

The issue you're facing is likely due to the server-side rendering (SSR) nature of Next.js. Lottie-web uses the window object, which is not available during SSR, causing the build to fail.

To fix this, you can dynamically import the Lottie component and disable SSR for it ([docs ref](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/optimizing/lazy-loading#nextdynamic)). Here's how your code can looks like:

```
import dynamic from 'next/dynamic';

const Lottie = dynamic(() => import('react-lottie'), { ssr: false });
// or lottie-react - depending on what library you use
```